# How to get global mod_rewrite rules working in XAMPP? (i.e. NOT using .htaccess files)

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, xampp

For some reason, every single tutorial/answer I find on creating `mod_rewrite` rules in Apache (or XAMPP, more specifically) only covers the use of **.htaccess** files, but I need to create "global" `mod_rewrite` rules, i.e. what is called "on the VirtualHost level" in the Apache docs.

I have enabled/uncommented the loading of the `mod_rewrite` module in the **httpd.conf** file, and as far as I understand it, all that should need to be done after that is to add the following lines at the right location in the Apache config:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?testtest/.* /test.php
```

(i.e. this test rule should rewrite all accesses to the URLs "http://localhost/testtest/*" to the URL "http://localhost/test.php")

I have also tried the "L" flag to rule out any strange other rewrites happening after my rewrite, as follows, but with no different results:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?testtest/.* /test.php [L]
```

The key words here I guess are "at the right location", because I have tried to insert those lines more or less everywhere, inside individual "Directory" directives and in the last lines of the **httpd.conf** file, but nothing seems to work? (yes, I restart Apache after each configuration change too)

I don't have any VirtualHost directives defined anywhere in the config except the default `VirtualHost _default_:443` in **httpd-ssl.conf** (i.e. neither in **httpd.conf** nor **httpd-vhosts.conf**), since I only run a single instance and want these rules to apply everywhere.

**So, to summarize it:**
In a default XAMPP installation (on Windows, if it matters), what is the minimal steps to get a global `mod_rewrite` rule working, e.g. the test rule listed above (and WITHOUT using any **.htaccess** files, as explained above)?